# problem with abstain calss value and received result in snorkel labeling package

Tags: python, labeling, snorkel

I am using Snorkel Labeling Package to programmatically label my unlabeled training data. I followed this like https://www.snorkel.org/use-cases/01-spam-tutorial

you should write several label function like:

```
from textblob import TextBlob

@labeling_function()
def lf_sent_blob(x):
    sent = TextBlob(x.text).sentiment.polarity 
    if sent>0:
        return positive
    elif sent<0:
        return negative
    else:
        #return neutral
        return ABSTAIN
```

then you define the list of label functions and apply that to your unlabeled data like here:

```
from snorkel.labeling.model import LabelModel
from snorkel.labeling import PandasLFApplier
from snorkel.labeling import LFAnalysis

lfs = [lf_sent_emoji, lf_has_special, lf_has_capital, lf_not_ABSTAIN_v2, lf_not_ABSTAIN_v1,
       lf_sent_blob]
# Apply the LFs to the unlabeled training data
applier = PandasLFApplier(lfs)
L_train = applier.apply(df)
# here you analyze your labels
LFAnalysis(L=L_train, lfs=lfs).lf_summary()
```

Here is my problem if at the beginning I define class labels values as below the analyzing result makes sense. for example coverage of labels or polarity of labels for lf_sent_blob label function makes sense. for example Polarity Infer the polarities of each LF based on evidence in a label matrix.

```
positive = 1
negative = 0
ABSTAIN = -1 # -1 should be reserved for abstain!?
```

[image]

However when I change it to which has better meaning for me:

```
positive = 1
negative = -1
ABSTAIN = 0
```

I receive this result that is not correct

[image]

This is my question, is -1 integer value reserved for ABSTAIN class in snorkel if yes all staff does make sense?!!! if yes why they did not mention it in their tutorials or documentations ?!

Comment: In one of their Github pages, they define -1 as abstain. https://github.com/som-shahlab/trove/blob/main/tutorials/3_Weakly_Supervised_NER.ipynb

Comment: There is another of their Github page where they define -1 as abstain. Check it out here: https://github.com/snorkel-team/snorkel-tutorials/blob/master/spouse/spouse_demo.ipynb